# How do I maintain a population of daphnia inside a filtered tank

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium

I have an aquarium with a HOB filter. I tried to introduce a large population of *Daphnia* to the tank, but by the next day, they had all been either eaten or filtered out. Is there any way to maintain a stable population of *Daphnia* in a filtered tank?

If it helps, I have a 55 gallon (210 L) tank with a few plants, some corys, a betta, a school of neon tetras, pom-pom crabs, and ghost shrimp.

I’m also a very inexperienced aquarium owner. This is my first tank.

This question is slightly different than:

[How do you breed Daphnia to feed to aquarium fish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18623/how-do-you-breed-daphnia-to-feed-to-aquarium-fish)

I am specifically interested in how to sustain a population of *Daphnia* in a community aquarium, rather than in a separate enclosure. Maybe it is not feasible/possible?

Comment: if you put daphnia in a tank where you have fish you can simply forget keeping daphnia alive.

Comment: you can take a look here https://www.aquariumcoop.com/blogs/aquarium/daphnia-culturing-how-to-raise-daphnia to see how to keep daphnia,there is lots of information about this on the net.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you breed daphnia to feed to aquarium fish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18623/how-do-you-breed-daphnia-to-feed-to-aquarium-fish)

Comment: @trondhansen thanks for your reply! I edited the question above; hopefully it is distinguished from the other question you linked. I'm wondering if I can build out a pool feature or something similar to have a still water zone to partially isolate the daphnia within the larger tank?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Did you have any luck in the end? I'm going to culture daphnia in another container to feed to my fish but it would be cool to have a working ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

I recommended a "hang on breeding box" on [another question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/24219/my-molly-is-nipping-at-one-of-the-cherry-barbs-in-my-tank-what-should-i-do-the/25323#25323) for separating grown fish. They're cheap and basically give both fish access to the filtered, temperature-appropriate water without giving them access to each other and without the need for a separate tank.

In a similar vein, I guess you could try a [fry hatchery](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Saim-Aquarium-Plastic-Hatchery-Breeder/dp/B01H1TQCC2/ref=asc_df_B01H1TQCC2/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=241051912230&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13062259952914802261&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9046834&hvtargid=pla-487374683759&psc=1). The daphnia could live inside it (if the mesh is fine enough), and you wouldn't need a second tank.

I must warn you that they sell live, frozen and dried daphnia as fish food here. My goldfish never really developed a taste for it (and the old one doesn't like his food to move on its own these days), so they didn't gorge on it but it would slowly be eaten over the course of a couple of hours. The bronze corys I had liked it well enough.

If you want to grow your own fish food, far easier to "fence off" plants than living creatures.